# Storing a negative number in MySQL DB from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've been able to successfully save data to the database however, when I try to store an entry such as:

```
1,1,"Description 1",-195.37
1,2,"Description 2",-175.90
1,3,"Description 3",108.00
1,4,"Description 4",-57.33
1,5,"Description 5",95.32
```

It spits up this:

```
---------------------------
Application Name Here
---------------------------
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ApplicationNameHere.frmPaySlip.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in frmPaySlip.vb:line 210
---------------------------
OK    
---------------------------
```

The database is laid out as follows:

```
psid    int(5)
rowid   int(5)
description varchar(255)
value   decimal(20,2)
```

Code I'm using is:

```
Dim cmd_result As Integer = CInt(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
Dim rowID As Integer = 1
selectCommand2.Connection = connection
selectCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `ps_payslip_datrow` (`psid`, `rowid`, `description`, `value`) VALUES (@psid, @rowid, @description, @value)"
selectCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psid", cmd_result)
selectCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowid", 0)
selectCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", 0)
selectCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", 0.00)
For Each item As ListViewItem In lbDedAddTot.Items
    selectCommand2.Parameters("@rowid").Value = rowID
    selectCommand2.Parameters("@description").Value = item.SubItems(0).Text
    selectCommand2.Parameters("@value").DbType = DbType.Decimal
    selectCommand2.Parameters("@value").Value = Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems(1).Text)
    selectCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    rowID += 1
Next
```

Notes:
cmd_result works perfectly fine. It's just this loop that's failing.
VB.NET is converting the number to a Decimal. Been doing break and watch to verify.
I've been trying to see where I've gone wrong the last two days.

Comment: Did u really want description to be a number?

Comment: This is where you REALLY should use add not addwithvalue so you do not get mixed value types.

Comment: You are setting the value for `@value` twice as well.  If it is really MySql use  `MySqlDbType` to specify the type.  And you could get rid of the whole thing if you used a bound datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line,
    **selectCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", 0)**
aren't you forgetting the quotes for 0 (zero)?

Comment: Of course. That's what happens when you stare at code for too long. :-P Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you inadvertently made "Description" an integer with that AddWithValue statement. Use Add method instead.

```
    selectCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `ps_payslip_datrow` (`psid`, `rowid`, `description`, `value`) VALUES (@psid, @rowid, @description, @value)"
    selectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@psid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmd_result
    selectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@rowid", SqlDbType.Int)
    selectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    selectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Decimal)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In lbDedAddTot.Items
        selectCommand2.Parameters("@rowid").Value = rowID
        selectCommand2.Parameters("@description").Value = item.SubItems(0).Text
        selectCommand2.Parameters("@value").Value = Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems(1).Text)
        selectCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        rowID += 1
    Next
```

You should also test the Value source to make sure it really is a decimal too.